MAUI ContentView that both exposes bindings and binds
If I inherit from ContentView to create a reusable control, I can make a control that binds its UI elements to it's own view model, or I can make a control that exposes a BindableProperty to its parent.  I haven't figured out how to do both.
To use a view model, I set the control's BindingContext to its view model in its constructor.  But this prevents any BindableProperty I create from working.
Is this possible?  Is there a good way to do this?  Is there a reason to avoid this pattern even if we could make it work?

you can use the source property in the binding expression to bind some elements to itself, and others to the BindingContext

If your custom control need a view model to bind to, place the view model as a child of your page's view model, and bind the control's BindingContext property to the property that holds your view model in the page's view model. Otherwise I would place all login in the control's code behind

Let's say we create a custom control with BindableProperty exposes,
public partial class CustomControl : ContentView
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty MyTextProperty =
  BindableProperty.Create("MyText", typeof(string), typeof(CustomControl), "");

    public string MyText
    {
        get => (string)GetValue(MyTextProperty);
        set => SetValue(MyTextProperty, value);
    }

...

And you want to set the BindingContext of CustomControl to its own ViewModel. So, you may set this.Content.BindingContext instead of this.BindingContext.
    public CustomControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Content.BindingContext = new CustomControlViewModel();
    }

That makes UI bind to its own viewmodel and BindableProperty expose to its parent both.
<ContentView xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
           .....
             x:Name="MyView">
       
        //this binds to the BindableProperty
        <Label Text="{Binding BindingContext.MyText, Source={x:Reference MyView}}"/>

       //this binds to its own viewModel
        <Label Text="{Binding CustomControlText}"/>

